# Adding a results column from a query

Tags: mysql

I have a users table, a positions table, and an associate users_positions table.

It looks something (minimally) like:

```
USERS
-----
id

USERS_POSITIONS
---------------
id
user_id (FK)
position_id (FK)
calendar_date (a specific date)

POSITIONS
---------
id
day (a day of the week)
title
```

Users can volunteer for zero or more positions on a position's day, which goes into the users_positions table along with a calendar_date. I'm populating a form with the positions, along with the record of whether the user has or has not volunteered for that position (which will be a checkbox), because the user is able to edit their record as any time.

To start off with, I've managed to pull the positions from the database, and also managed to pull a join which only returns the the positions the user has volunteered for, but was wondering if MySQL has a feature that would create some kind of extra column from the query that would return all the positions and in the extra column, mark them as volunteered for or not. With this, I could check or uncheck those checkboxes with the information when generating the form.

The only other way I could think of would be to use php to get an array of the position rows for that day, then an array of the join rows which showed which rows the user had volunteered for. Then iterate through them both creating a new array with the data I described in the previous paragraph.

If there was a way to do this in MySQL though, it would of course be preferred. So can MySQL do something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN`. This will return all the rows from the first table, even if they don't match the table you're joining with. If there's no match, the values in the second table will be `NULL`, and you can test for that when showing whether the position has a volunteer.

```
SELECT day, title, IF(up.id IS NULL, "No", "Yes") volunteered
FROM Positions AS p
LEFT JOIN Users_Positions AS up ON p.id = up.position_id AND up.user_id = @user_id
```

Comment: Can you explain me what "up" mean?

Comment: It's a table alias, so you don't have to write out the full table name every time you refer to a column.

Comment: `Users_Positions AS up` makes `up` an alias for `Users_Positions`.

Comment: This is basic SQL syntax.

Comment: Ah yes sorry, I was missing the third line where I can see "AS" keyword. Thx

Comment: Thanks, this is a great explanation. I love MySQL, but sometimes find it hard to 'think' in it. Just to note, there were a couple of type-o's; Users_Postions and @user_id.

Comment: `@user_id` is not a typo, it's a MySQL user variable that I'm using as a placeholder for whichever user you're displaying the information for.